# Truncate table not working with SQL server sqlalchemy engine and pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I can successfully query and insert data using sqlalchemy and pandas:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
engine = create_engine('mssql://myserver/mydb?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
```

Read tempy table:

```
sql_command = """
select top 100 * from tempy
"""

df = pd.read_sql(sql_command, engine)
print df

   tempID  tempValue
0       1          2
```

Append new data:

```
df_append = pd.DataFrame( [[4,6]] , columns=['tempID','tempValue']) 
df_append.to_sql(name='tempy', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)

df = pd.read_sql(sql_command, engine)
print df

   tempID  tempValue
0       1          2
1       4          6
```

*Try* to truncate data:

```
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute( '''TRUNCATE TABLE tempy''' )
connection.close()
```

Read table again, but truncate failed:

```
df = pd.read_sql(sql_command, engine)
print df

   tempID  tempValue
0       1          2
1       4          6
```

Comment: Did you try committing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. What is your Pandas and SQLAlchemy version? BTW you don't have to create `connection` object, the following will work as well: `engine.execute('truncate table tempy')`

Comment: @MaxU pandas 0.9.1 and sqlalchemy 1.0.13

Comment: @univerio thanks for the tip on committing

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.execute('''TRUNCATE TABLE tempy''')
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Answer (score 43):

I have the same problem with `pandas` 0.19.2 and sqlalchemy `1.1.5`.

As I see `autocommit` is not forced in `engine.execute()` when running a `TRUNCATE` statement. If I force it manually then `TRUNCATE` works perfectly:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import text as sa_text

engine.execute(sa_text('''TRUNCATE TABLE tempy''').execution_options(autocommit=True))
```

It's fancy that `DROP` works perfectly without forcing `autocommit`...

Comment: Thanks! `autocommit` was the key.

Comment: @ragesz The reason why autocommit is not needed for `DROP` is that many RDBMS make some DDL instructions non-transactional. Worse, they can trigger the commit of an ongoing transaction. So, the exact behavior defining which query will need autocommit or not is vendor specific.

Comment: would not work anymore: 'LegacyCursorResult' object has no attribute 'execution_options'

Answer (score 15):

Here is a full solution based from the question, using sqlalchemy 1.1.15 on Windows I was receiving errors trying to implement the other solutions:

```
import sqlalchemy
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('mssql://myserver/mydb?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?trusted_connection=yes')
connection = engine.connect()
truncate_query = sqlalchemy.text("TRUNCATE TABLE tempy")
connection.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute(truncate_query)
```

Answer (score 9):

After trying the solution posted by ragesz and it not working for me (my sqlalchemy version is `1.3.9`), I got the following to work instead:

```
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execution_options(autocommit=True).execute("TRUNCATE TABLE foo;")
```

Answer (score 4):

SQLAlchemy_2 recommends using a context manager (`with` block) to manage the scope of transactions. In this case, the most straightforward approach is to use

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("TRUNCATE TABLE tempy")
```

When the context manager exits, the transaction is automatically committed. Note that this is different from `with engine.connect() as conn:`, which requires an explicit `.commit()`

```py
with engine.connect() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("TRUNCATE TABLE tempy")
    conn.commit()
```

When using `.execute()` with a Session, the statement must be wrapped in the SQLAlchemy `text()` function. We can either `.commit()` explicitly

```py
with Session(engine) as sess:
    sess.execute(text("TRUNCATE TABLE tempy"))
    sess.commit()
```

or we can `.begin()` the transaction explicitly, in which case we do not have to call `.commit()` ourselves

```py
with Session(engine) as sess, sess.begin():
    sess.execute(text("TRUNCATE TABLE tempy"))
```

Note also that "autocommit" is not required in any of these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Another quick and dirty version which works for me at SQLAlchemy: 2.0.15 is invoking the commit manually:

```
connection.execute(text('TRUNCATE TABLE foo;COMMIT'))
```