# Deleting all rows in SQL Server Database with Python (Pandas?)

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, truncate

I'm trying to use a python script to delete all rows (truncate) a table in a SQL Server database.

The below code runs but seems to hang indefinitely. If I try to run a select on the SQL table in SSMS, it also hangs, so I am assuming that the code is accessing the table but nothing is happening. When I restart the kernel the SQL table opens up and I can query it again.

I've used this code with select queries and it worked fine but perhaps it's not meant for deletes or edits. I've also tried a 'delete from' command.

Thanks all!

```
import pyodbc

sql_conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL Server};Server=servername;Database=dbname;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=login;PWD=password')

query = "truncate table tablename"

pd.read_sql(query, sql_conn)
```

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079419/truncate-table-not-working-with-sql-server-sqlalchemy-engine-and-pandas

Comment: Thanks Anky. I searched all those keywords but didn't come across that question! It worked :)

Comment: The solution on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079419/truncate-table-not-working-with-sql-server-sqlalchemy-engine-and-pandas) solved the problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Truncate table not working with SQL server sqlalchemy engine and pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42079419/truncate-table-not-working-with-sql-server-sqlalchemy-engine-and-pandas)