# Pytest- How to remove created data after each test function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I have a FastAPI + SQLAlchemy project and I'm using Pytest for writing unit tests for the APIs.

In each test function, I create some data in some tables (user table, post table, comment table, etc) using SQLAlchemy. These created data in each test function will remain in the tables after test function finished and will affect on other test functions.

For example, in the first test function I create 3 posts, and 2 users, then in the second test functions, these 3 posts and 2 users remained on the tables and makes my test expectations wrong.

Following is my fixture for pytest:

```
@pytest.fixture
def session(engine):
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    yield session
    session.rollback()  # Removes data created in each test method
    session.close()  # Close the session after each test
```

I used `session.rollback()` to remove all created data during session, but it doesn't remove data.

And the following is my test functions:

```
class TestAllPosts(PostBaseTestCase):

    def create_logged_in_user(self, db):
        user = self.create_user(db)
        return user.generate_tokens()["access"]

    def test_can_api_return_all_posts_without_query_parameters(self, client, session):
        posts_count = 5
        user_token = self.create_logged_in_user(session)
        for i in range(posts_count):
            self.create_post(session)

        response = client.get(url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {user_token}"})
        assert response.status_code == 200
        json_response = response.json()
        assert len(json_response) == posts_count

    def test_can_api_detect_there_is_no_post(self, client, session):
        user_token = self.create_logged_in_user(session)
        response = client.get(url, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {user_token}"})
        assert response.status_code == 404
```

In the latest test function, instead of getting 404, I get 200 with 5 posts (from the last test function)

How can I remove the created data in each test function after test function finished?

Comment: [doc](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.rollback) said the rollback method only rolls back in-progress transactions. You need to re-think your test roll back strategy.

Comment: @HaiVu Is there a better solution? I need to remove all created rows (in all tables) during the test function. (The same as Django does in its test framework)

Comment: I am sorry, I don't have a solution for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that there are **multiple sessions**.

One is used by your tests. The other one(s) is/are used by the server.

Because you are using `client.get`, you are sending a request to the server, which will use its own database session.

1. To solve your problem you can just truncate all tables at the end of each test: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25220958/5521670

```py
@pytest.fixture
def session(engine):
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    yield session

    # Remove any data from database (even data not created by this session)
    with contextlib.closing(engine.connect()) as connection:
        transaction = connection.begin()
        connection.execute(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {",".join(table.name for table in reversed(Base.metadata.sorted_tables)} RESTART IDENTITY CASCADE;'))
        transaction.commit()

    session.rollback()  # Removes data created in each test method
    session.close()  # Close the session after each test
```

2. Another alternative would be to make the server use your test session (just like the FastAPI documentation suggests): https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-database/

```py
def override_get_db():
    try:
        db = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db
```

Comment: You're right. The problem was my session in API and in tests is not the same.
Thanks

Comment: With #1, you can still have race conditions, e.g. a second session starts before fixture from the first session has cleaned the data. The only real solution is isolation. This can be at the DB level (like a temp, per session, local DB), table level (e.g. a fixture to create a table with unique name), or even at the record level (e.g. the session fixture tracks it's own data, asserts only on own data, and cleans up only own data). I personally prefer DB level, as it forces me to create some code to create and bootstrap the test DB, which helps in the long run.

Comment: @ThomasD Can you give me some useful links? I don't know anything about database-level isolation and how can I use them. thanks

Comment: @ThomasD thanks for pointing out the race condition! I am aware that `COMMIT` can be asynchronous and return response even before all changes were fully applied. However, `TRUNCATE` should have an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, so it shouldn't happen that data will leak between tests (and I've never seen it happen when using pattern either). Although, you do have to look out for tests that spawn threads, or any other form of background workers, which are not automatically cleaned up and can still write data to the database after the `TRUNCATE` was committed (and therefore leak data between tests).

Answer (score 1):

After you commit a transaction you can't rollback to the state before the commit.
According to Durability in ACID principles once you commit a transaction the rollback won't affect the committed data:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/188653/rollback-after-commit

So you should delete those records manually.

Edit:

You can use truncate statement which removes all the records in a table:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.3/en/truncate-table.html

Note: Consider truncating tables which there is no reference to their Primary key to avoid inconsistency errors.

Here's an example of truncating using SqlAlchemy:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42097818/12961420

Comment: It's not a scalable approach to remove them manually. I need an automated approach to remove all created rows In all tables after test function finished

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/absent1706/3ccc1722ea3ca23a5cf54821dbc813fb

Comment: Here's another example: https://dev.to/whchi/implement-laravel-like-refreshdatabase-in-fastapi-1fil

Answer (score 1):

First off, ideally your unit tests should not depend on each other. Maybe you need to consider re-designing them so that they can be executed randomly. I know sometimes it takes an extra work to do so...

> I used session.rollback() to remove all created data during session, but it doesn't remove data.

That's because the change has been commited. If you commit your changes, rollback doesn't affect them. It's only affecting the ongoing transaction.

There are two possible solutions here:

1. Do not commit. After opening a transaction(inside your tests), create your posts and whatever, then don't commit them, they will be rollbacked with you current fixture and won't affect the database. You still be able to read the changes and confirm that your tests are indeed working. (take a look at [isolation levels](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_transaction.html#setting-transaction-isolation-levels-dbapi-autocommit) for more information)

**Note**: You should specify the scope of `"function"` for your fixture so that the rollback happens in every single test.

**Note**: Remember if you use the `with sesison.begin()` context manager inside your tests, it will commit the changes when exiting the `with` block. If you chose to do this solution, you should avoid doing that. A bare `session.begin()` is enough for opening a transaction.

2. Inside your tests, delete the objects you created and *commit* the session again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Without commit, can data be inserted (or updated) in the database? I commented all `session.commit()` calls in my tests, but all of them now return 404.

Comment: @msln Without commit, the changes (insert/update) are not persisted in the database. Which means other connections(or transactions - depending on the isolation level) won't be able to see them, but the current session which have opened the transaction can see the changes. So if you need to query and get the newly inserted data, you need to pass the session object that started the transaction.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass session from the test function to the API function. So, I think I have reached a dead end!

Comment: @msln Yes in that situation you're out of luck with the first solution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to have a fixture that would truncate the tables before every test, so you would use it on the class like so:

```
import pytest
from sqlalchemy import text
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from models import user, post


@pytest.fixture()
def clean_db(session: Session):
    tables = [user.__tablename__, post.__tablename__]
    for table in tables:
        session.execute(text(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {table}'))
    session.commit()
```

and in the tests class:

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.usefixtures("clean_db", autouse=True)
class TestAllPosts(PostBaseTestCase):

...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `truncate` the tables before every test:-

```
@pytest.fixture()
def clear(session: Session):
    data = [user.__tablename__, post.__tablename__]
    for i in data:
        session.execute(text(f'TRUNCATE TABLE {i}'))
    session.commit()
```

Now within the test class just use this annotation, followed by your code:-

`@pytest.mark.usefixtures("clear", autouse=True)`